# Math in a Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

I want to use

```
wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed
```

to get the NIC speed.

However, I want to do some Math on the Speed to get a more sensible figure, i.e. 1000Mbps or 100Mbps. How can you do such Math in Batch?

Comment: Do you need the Header "Name . . . Speed"?   Is Mbps sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

You can do simple math in batch-files.
You can use `set /a var=1+1` and `set /a var=%var%+1` etc.

In your example it would be (for just the speed):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic nic where NetEnabled^=true get speed /value ^| find /i "speed"') do set /a speed=%%a
echo Speed in bytes: %speed% Bps
set /a speed=%speed%/1024
echo Speed in kilobytes: %speed% Kbs
set /a speed=%speed%/1024
echo Speed in megabytes: %speed% Mbs
```

Comment: Note that you can also specify a modify on itself as `set /a "speed/=1024"`.

Comment: @david, yes, i forgot about that one. [Here](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) is a more complete list.

Comment: Why the '^' before '=' and '|'

Comment: @FrK because `=` and `|` are special characters who need to be escaped (See [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)). If you execute this without them, the `=` and `|` are executed too soon. (i.e. the **whole** text before `=` is seen as variable and everything after as value to assign to the variable. We want the `=` only to be executed in the `wmic`-command and not before. This also goes for the pipe-sign. (I hope i'm explaining this clearly enough) (If execute without the `^` you'll get errors. `true - Invalid alias verb.` and `| was unexpected at this time.`)